# Odd URL RewriteRule Behaviour

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

Hoping someone with better experience can guide me on this.

Ref: https://www.donbur.co.uk/gb-en/news/index.php

This is a dynamically generated news summary list with a button link to article pages.  Until last week, the button links worked fine.

Each link calls a URL

```html
<a class="button" href="https://www.donbur.co.uk/news/<?php echo rawurlencode($row_newsResult['newsurlkey']);?>">Read full article</a>
```

This parses fine.

To process this link, I've then got an htaccess RewriteRule:

```html
RewriteRule ^news/([^/]*)$ /gb-en/news/article.php?title=$1 [L]
```

The article.php file then uses the unique title to identify and show the full article.... or at least that's what it should do and has done.

For whatever reason, from the news index.php page, when the link is clicked, it just refreshes the page and re-writes the URL to

```html
https://www.donbur.co.uk/gb-en/news/index.php/[uniquetitleparameter]?title=[uniquetitleparameter]
```

The parts in brackets [] obviously get populated with the rawurlencoded string.

I cannot for the life of me understand what is happening here - especially when I have a similar page, doing a very similar thing, works absolutely fine (https://www.donbur.co.uk/gb-en/features/feature-list.php)!!!!

This all started going wrong when I converted the site from http to https: but can't work out if that's relevant??

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: @anubhava did that.  Not sure how you view 301/302 redirects but when I then clicked the links - it worked!!  Do I understand this was a cached htaccess rule?  I didn't know that happened...

Comment: Yes it appears to be bad browser caching issue.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was just a bad caching issue.  Temporarily disabled cache as suggested and all works well.